# Using a bash variables in sqlcmd

Tags: bash, sqlcmd

I have been tasked with replacing ISQL in a lot of our bash scripts with sqlcmd. ISQL allows piping a variable in it's execution.
An example would be:

```
    SQL_STATEMENT="SELECT TOP 1 SYS_USER_NAME FROM SYS_USER"
    echo $SQL_STATEMENT | isql -b -d, $DSN $DBUID $DBPWD >> setupdb_test.txt
```

From what I can tell this is not viable in sqlcmd. How can I do this? What flags does sqlcmd have to allow this to happen?

Here is what I have tried and have had a good result BUT I really do not want to create the file sql_command.sql every time a particular script runs:

```
    echo "SELECT TOP 1 SYS_USER_NAME FROM SYS_USER" > sql_command.sql
    sqlcmd -S $DB -U $DBUID -P $DBPWD -d $DSN -i sql_command.sql >> setupdb_test.txt
```

Comment: have you tried this?

    `export SQL_COMMAND="SELECT TOP 1 SYS_USER_NAME FROM SYS_USER";`
    `sqlcmd -S $DB -U $DBUID -P $DBPWD -d $DSN -i $SQL_COMMAND >> setupdb_test.txt`

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. I get an error of:
Sqlcmd: 'SELECT': Invalid filename.

Comment: ok. the SQL_COMMAND contain space, so the $SQL_COMMAND must be quoted. Like this: `sqlcmd -S $DB -U $DBUID -P $DBPWD -d $DSN -i "$SQL_COMMAND" >> setupdb_test.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programs originating on Windows can be picky about how they handle non-regular files and I don't have the opportunity to test, but you can try the typical Unix tricks for providing a "file" with data from an `echo`.

Either `/dev/stdin`:

```
echo "SELECT TOP 1 SYS_USER_NAME FROM SYS_USER" | sqlcmd -S "$DB" -U "$DBUID" -P "$DBPWD" -d "$DSN" -i /dev/stdin
```

or process substitution:

```
sqlcmd -S "$DB" -U "$DBUID" -P "$DBPWD" -d "$DSN" -i <(echo "SELECT TOP 1 SYS_USER_NAME FROM SYS_USER")
```

Comment: This works, I also tried
        SQL_COMMAND="SELECT TOP 1 SYS_USER_NAME FROM SYS_USER"
echo $SQL_COMMAND | sqlcmd -S $DB -U $DBUID -P $DBPWD -d $DSN -i /dev/stdin >> setupdb_test.txt
and this works as well. Thank you.